# Triangle two angles and one length

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle ABC, the angle at A is 41 degrees, the angle at B is 71 degrees, and the length of side AB is 8.  To 2 decimal places, what is the length of side BC?

I got this answer 5.66. is that correct? I used sinerule.

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sine rule, $$\frac{AB}{\sin 68^\circ}=\frac{BC}{\sin 41^\circ}$$ so your answer is correct.